# I need to hide a radio button in a quiz app android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, radio-button, android-sqlite

I would like to ask for some help with my android code. I am trying to develop a quiz app using SQLite.Number of possible answers differs so i need to hide radio buttons from the main screen if answers e.g. are 3 and not 4 (4 is by default the number of the radio buttons). Tried to use:

`if (DataContract.QuestionTable.COLUMN_ANSWER4.isEmpty ()){ radioButton4.setVisibility (View.INVISIBLE); }`

but does not seem to work.I'm new in android programming and this is my first project so every comment will be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: We need to show error, can you share the error on console ?

Comment: There is no error in console...just not work...button is still visible with no text.

Comment: If i put the cursor on code the pop up box shows that: Condition 'DataContract.QuestionTable.COLUMN_ANSWER4 == null' is always 'false'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a demo with a suggested technique, considering the limited amount of code posted with the question.

This utilises two tables to conform with a normalised approach. A table for the questions and a table for answers. Each answer (the Children) has a link/map/relationship/association with a single Question (the Parent). To prevent referential integrity issues a Foreign Key constraint has been used.

First a few POJO's for the **Questions**, the **Answers** and **QuestionWithAnswers** (i.e. it's answers)

**QuestionPOJO**

```
class QuestionPOJO {
    long questionId;
    String questionText;

    public QuestionPOJO(long questionId, String questionText) {
        this.questionId = questionId;
        this.questionText = questionText;
    }

    public long getQuestionId() {
        return questionId;
    }

    public void setQuestionId(long questionId) {
        this.questionId = questionId;
    }

    public String getQuestionText() {
        return questionText;
    }

    public void setQuestionText(String questionText) {
        this.questionText = questionText;
    }
}
```

**AnswerPOJO**

```
class AnswerPOJO {
    long answerId;
    long questionMap;
    String answerText;
    boolean correct = false;

    public AnswerPOJO(long answerid, long questionMap, String answerText, boolean correct) {
        this.answerId = answerid;
        this.questionMap = questionMap;
        this.answerText = answerText;
        this.correct = correct;
    }

    public long getAnswerId() {
        return answerId;
    }

    public void setAnswerId(long answerId) {
        this.answerId = answerId;
    }

    public long getQuestionMap() {
        return questionMap;
    }

    public void setQuestionMap(long questionMap) {
        this.questionMap = questionMap;
    }

    public boolean isCorrect() {
        return correct;
    }

    public void setCorrect(boolean correct) {
        this.correct = correct;
    }

    public String getAnswerText() {
        return answerText;
    }

    public void setAnswerText(String answerText) {
        this.answerText = answerText;
    }
}
```

and **QuestionWithAnswerPOJO**

```
class QuestionWithAnswersPOJO {
    QuestionPOJO question;
    ArrayList<AnswerPOJO> answers = new ArrayList<>();

    public QuestionWithAnswersPOJO(QuestionPOJO question, List<AnswerPOJO> answers) {
        this.question = question;
        this.answers.clear();
        this.answers.addAll(answers);
    }

    public QuestionPOJO getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(QuestionPOJO question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public ArrayList<AnswerPOJO> getAnswers() {
        return answers;
    }

    public void setAnswers(ArrayList<AnswerPOJO> answers) {
        this.answers = answers;
    }
}
```

Now the DatabaseHelper, that handles all the database activity. Including methods to add and get Questions and the Answers and notably to get the Answers that belong to a question.

```
class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "questions.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String QUESTION_TABLE = "question";
    public static final String QUESTION_ID_COLUMN = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String QUESTION_TEXT_COLUMN = "question_text";
    public static final String ANSWER_TABLE = "answer";
    public static final String ANSWER_ID_COLUMN = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String ANSWER_TEXT_COLUMN = "answer_text";
    public static final String ANSWER_QUESTION_MAP_COLUMN = "question_map";
    public static final String ANSWER_CORRECT_COLUMN = "correct";

    private static volatile DatabaseHelper instance = null;
    private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    private static SQLiteDatabase db = null;

    public static DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context, boolean forceOpen) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        }
        if (forceOpen) {
            db = instance.getWritableDatabase();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + QUESTION_TABLE + "(" +
                QUESTION_ID_COLUMN + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                QUESTION_TEXT_COLUMN + " TEXT" +
                ");");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + ANSWER_TABLE + "(" +
                ANSWER_ID_COLUMN + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                ANSWER_TEXT_COLUMN + " TEXT," +
                ANSWER_QUESTION_MAP_COLUMN + " INTEGER REFERENCES " + QUESTION_TABLE + "(" + QUESTION_ID_COLUMN + ") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE," +
                ANSWER_CORRECT_COLUMN + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0 /* false */" +
                ");");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    }

    // Fully comprehensive Question insert
    public long insertQuestion(Long questionId, String questionText) {
        init_db_AsWriteableDatabase();
        long rv = -2;
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        if (questionId != null && questionId > 0) {
            cv.put(QUESTION_ID_COLUMN,questionId);
        }
        if (questionText != null && questionText.length() > 0) {
            cv.put(QUESTION_TEXT_COLUMN,questionText);
        }
        if (cv.size() > 0) {
            rv = db.insert(QUESTION_TABLE,null,cv);
        }
        return rv;
    }

    // Concise Question insert
    public long insertQuestion(String questionText) {
        return insertQuestion(null,questionText);
    }

    // Fully comprehensive Answer insert
    public long insertAnswer(Long answerId, long questionMap, String answerText, boolean correct) {
        init_db_AsWriteableDatabase();
        long rv = -2;
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        if (answerId != null && answerId > 0) {
            cv.put(ANSWER_ID_COLUMN,answerId);
        }
        if (answerText != null && answerText.length() > 0) {
            cv.put(ANSWER_CORRECT_COLUMN,correct);
            cv.put(ANSWER_TEXT_COLUMN,answerText);
            cv.put(ANSWER_QUESTION_MAP_COLUMN,questionMap);
            rv = db.insert(ANSWER_TABLE,null,cv);
        }
        return rv;
    }

    // long concise Answer insert
    public long insertAnswer(long questionMap, String answerText, boolean correct) {
        return insertAnswer(null,questionMap,answerText,correct);
    }
    public long insertAnswer(long questionMap, String answerText) {
        return insertAnswer(questionMap,answerText,false);
    }
    // short concise Answer insert
    private void init_db_AsWriteableDatabase() {
        if (db == null) {
            db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        }
    }


    @SuppressLint("Range")
    public QuestionPOJO getQuestionById(long questionId) {
        QuestionPOJO rv = null;
        init_db_AsWriteableDatabase();
        Cursor csr = db.query(QUESTION_TABLE,null,QUESTION_ID_COLUMN+"=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(questionId)},null,null,null);
        if (csr.moveToNext()) {
            rv = new QuestionPOJO(csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(QUESTION_ID_COLUMN)),csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(QUESTION_TEXT_COLUMN)));
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }

    @SuppressLint("Range")
    public List<AnswerPOJO> getAnswersForQuestion(long questionId, boolean onlyCorrect) {
        init_db_AsWriteableDatabase();
        ArrayList<AnswerPOJO> rv = new ArrayList<>();
        StringBuilder whereClause = new StringBuilder();
        whereClause.append(ANSWER_QUESTION_MAP_COLUMN + "=?");
        if (onlyCorrect) {
            whereClause.append(" AND ").append(ANSWER_CORRECT_COLUMN);
        }
        Cursor csr = db.query(ANSWER_TABLE,null,whereClause.toString(),new String[]{String.valueOf(questionId)},null,null,null);
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            rv.add(
                new AnswerPOJO(
                        csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(ANSWER_ID_COLUMN)),
                        questionId,
                        csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(ANSWER_TEXT_COLUMN)),
                        csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(ANSWER_CORRECT_COLUMN)) > 0
                )
            );
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }
}
```

Finally to put it all together and activity that has a layout for 4 radio buttons along with the associated answer as a TextView.

So the layout is:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!">
    </TextView>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/question_radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answer1_radioButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:ignore="DuplicateSpeakableTextCheck"></RadioButton>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/answer1_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answer2_radioButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </RadioButton>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/answer2_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answer3_radioButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </RadioButton>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/answer3_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answer4_radioButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </RadioButton>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/answer4_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

- simple enough to show how hiding the buttons depending upon the number of answers (or a limit according to the number of Buttons/Textviews)

And the activity to demonstrate:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    RadioButton[] radiobuttons = new RadioButton[4];
    TextView[] answerTexts = new TextView[4];
    QuestionWithAnswersPOJO currentQuestionWithAnswers;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /*
            prepare Radion Buttons and associated TextViews
         */
        radiobuttons[0] = this.findViewById(R.id.answer1_radioButton);
        radiobuttons[1] = this.findViewById(R.id.answer2_radioButton);
        radiobuttons[2] = this.findViewById(R.id.answer3_radioButton);
        radiobuttons[3] = this.findViewById(R.id.answer4_radioButton);
        answerTexts[0] = this.findViewById(R.id.answer1_textview);
        answerTexts[1] = this.findViewById(R.id.answer2_textview);
        answerTexts[2] = this.findViewById(R.id.answer3_textview);
        answerTexts[3] = this.findViewById(R.id.answer4_textview);

        /*
            Prepare to use Database
         */
        dbHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(this,true);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        /* Clear any existing data for consistent results */
        db.delete(DatabaseHelper.ANSWER_TABLE,null,null);
        db.delete(DatabaseHelper.QUESTION_TABLE,null,null);
        /* Add some demo data  1 question with 5 answers (comment out to reduce number of answers)*/
        long q1id = dbHelper.insertQuestion("What is 1 + 1");
        dbHelper.insertAnswer(q1id,"It is 1");
        dbHelper.insertAnswer(q1id,"it is 2", true);
        dbHelper.insertAnswer(q1id,"It is 3");
        dbHelper.insertAnswer(q1id,"It is 4");
        dbHelper.insertAnswer(q1id,"It is something Else"); // will be ignored because only 4 radio buttons

        /* Get the question with the answers, however many ot has */
        currentQuestionWithAnswers = new QuestionWithAnswersPOJO(dbHelper.getQuestionById(q1id),dbHelper.getAnswersForQuestion(q1id,false));
        /* setup (refresh) the radio buttons and textviews */
        getAndSetRadioButtons(currentQuestionWithAnswers);
    }

    /*
        Does as it says
     */
    private void getAndSetRadioButtons(QuestionWithAnswersPOJO qwa) {
        // Clear All

        for (int i=0;i < radiobuttons.length; i++) {
            radiobuttons[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
            answerTexts[i].setText("");
            answerTexts[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        /* show only the least of answers/radio buttons */
        int numberToShow = radiobuttons.length;
        if (qwa.answers.size() < radiobuttons.length) {
            numberToShow = qwa.answers.size();
        }
        int i = 0;
        for(AnswerPOJO a: qwa.answers) {
            if (i < numberToShow) {
                radiobuttons[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                answerTexts[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                answerTexts[i++].setText(a.answerText);
            } else {
                /* nothing more to do so early break out of the loop */
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Results**

**Result 1 - run with the 5 answers *(see comments re 5th answer)***

[image]

**Result 2 - All bar 1 answer comment out so the question has just the 1 answer**

The code used:-

```
    long q1id = dbHelper.insertQuestion("What is 1 + 1");
    dbHelper.insertAnswer(q1id,"It is 1");
    //dbHelper.insertAnswer(q1id,"it is 2", true);
    //dbHelper.insertAnswer(q1id,"It is 3");
    //dbHelper.insertAnswer(q1id,"It is 4");
    //dbHelper.insertAnswer(q1id,"It is something Else"); // will be ignored because only 4 radio buttons
```

The display :-

[image]

**Result 3 - first and 5th answers only inserted**

[image]

and so on.

---

Additional after code has been posted.

***Additional Answer as code has now been added.***

You say:-

> Tried to use:
> `if (DataContract.QuestionTable.COLUMN_ANSWER4.isEmpty ()){  radioButton4.setVisibility (View.INVISIBLE); }`
> but does not seem to work.

If **DataContract.QuestionTable.COLUMN_ANSWER4** were empty then would be facing more serious issues as it is the **column name**.

You should be checking for the contents of the column which has been retrieved from DB and placed into **currentQuestion**, for the question being inspected.

I believe that using (old code commented out):-

```
        radioButton1.setText(currentQuestion.getAnswer1 ());
        radioButton2.setText(currentQuestion.getAnswer2 ());
        radioButton3.setText(currentQuestion.getAnswer3 ());
        radioButton4.setText(currentQuestion.getAnswer4 ());
        if(currentQuestion.getAnswer4() == null || currentQuestion.getAnswer4().isEmpty()) {
            radioButton4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            radioButton4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // just in case it is INVISIBLE
            radioButton4.setText(currentQuestion.getAnswer4());
        }
        /*
        if (DataContract.QuestionTable.COLUMN_ANSWER4.isEmpty ()){
            radioButton4.setVisibility (View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            radioButton4.setText(currentQuestion.getAnswer4 ());
        }
         */
```

Will resolve this issue. e.g. at Q3:-

[image]

Comment: Dear Mike, thank you so much for your amazing answer even my code is a little different in structure. I'll post my code so it will be easier for people to answer. It was my first post on Stackoverflow so i was not so specific to what i need!! But thank yo anyway!! You are amazing and i'll try to put what you suggested in my code. Best regards!!

Comment: @fotonio recheck the answer

Comment: Thank you so much Mike for your useful correction. It works perfectly!!